# I upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04 LTS but boots only when my external drive is plugged in. Why?

Tags: reboot, automount

I just upgraded my machine from 20.04 to 22.04.
Everything works, except for this strange behavior.

I have this external HDD which contains just backup of my computer, but it needs to remain plugged in while booting. If I remove it, my laptop doesn't boot. No it doesn't have any partition or anything to boot.

This is how my fstab looks like:

```
john@john-EON15-X:~$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=xx3657a9-xx89-xx5c-xxf4-xx1ac457550c   /                           ext4    errors=remount-ro   0 1 

!# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation

UUID=xx7B-xxF8                              /boot/efi                   vfat    umask=0077          0 1 

/swapfile                                   none                        swap    sw                  0 0 

/dev/sdb1                                   /media/john/TMC-SoundRoom   exfat   defaults            0 0
```

The "TMC-SoundRoom" is my external hdd. If I remove (ofcourse safely remove it) it reboots, and I get this error
[image: The boot stops here, and no keypress is taken except "enter" key]

And another strange thing, except "enter" key, I cant type anything else.
I have to do a hard boot on the machine.

Comment: Change defaults for your exfat filesystem to `noauto,nofail`  Meaning noauto do not mount when "mount -a" is given (e.g., at boot time) nofail do not bother me with errors if the device is not present.

Comment: Awesome that works. So for my case I just added nofail (skipping the noauto). That way when I insert the external drive it automatically mounts.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the user who nudged me to the right response. So in my case I added this line to my fstab and it all works good (for now).

```
/dev/sdb1                                   /media/john/TMC-SoundRoom   exfat   nofail,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec,umask=003 0 0
```

Comment: It would be better to use uuid for it instead of the device name.